# Дополнительные поля <input> с нумерацией

Tags: javascript, html

При клике на "Add new position" нужно, чтобы не только добавлялись инпуты с `name`, как у предыдущего.
Но и шла их нумерация в `name`.
Скажем, у первого `name="name"`, я нажимаю добавить и появляется инпут с `name="name-1"`.
Каким способом это делается?
HTML разметка:

```
<form class="main-form" action="send.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nameCompany" placeholder="Name company">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Contact first name*">
    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Contact last name*">
    <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*" pattern="^[ 0-9]+$">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*">

    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <h2>Order content</h2>
      <div class="newCell">
        <input type="textSku" placeholder="sku">
        <input type="textName" placeholder="name">
        <input type="numberQuantity" placeholder="quantity">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-plus">
      <input type="button" id="add" value="Add new position"></input>
    </div>
    <label for="delivery">Delivery Date:</label>
    <input id="delivery" type="date" placeholder="Delivery date">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Payment method">
    <label for="payment">Date of payment:</label>
    <input id="payment" type="date" placeholder="Date of payment">


    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто при клике считаем сколько уже есть инпутов, которые начинаются с `name`, но думаю можно и классы добавить и по ним считать, а потом к новым инпутам добавлять это значение в название, вот убрал с формы всё кроме `name`:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
  
  const inputsCounter = $('.main-form').find('input[name^="name"]').length;
  console.log(inputsCounter);
  
  const inputName = 'name-' + inputsCounter;
  $('<input type="text" name="' + inputName + '" value="' + inputName + '" />').appendTo('.inputs');
  console.log(inputsCounter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="main-form" action="send.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Contact first name*">
    
    <div class="inputs"></div>

    <div class="button-plus">
      <input type="button" id="add" value="Add new position"></input>
    </div>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
```

Только изменить нужно контейнер, куда это всё вставлять, но и код вставки.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю 2 способа, первый предпочтительнее, как по мне:

1. Необходимо, чтобы все добавляемые теги `<input name="name_N" value="" />` были помещены в отдельный контейнер. Тогда в момент генерации нового поля можно считать количество уже добавленных полей и эту цифру конкатенацией добавлять к имени нового поля.
2. В атрибуте самой кнопки добавления хранить порядковый номер и после каждого добавлении нового поля увеличивать этот счётчик на 1